# Direct users to use Uber for Business using Deeplink

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone, uber-api

We would like to add the Uber Deeplink functionality to our iOS, Android and Windows Phone app. Our users are business users. The business wants them to travel using Uber for Business so their expenses will be paid by our business.

Some questions:

1. What is the purpose of the client_id parameter keeping in mind we would like to use Uber for Business? I've mailed myself two Deeplinks to test the implementation, one with and one without the client_id parameter; I saw no difference between these two when opening the Uber app using the Deeplink. Also the developer pages only gives information regarding Affiliate tracking: *In order to attribute any deep linking action back to your application, be sure to always include the client_id parameter.*
2. We would like to remind the users that they need to check their invitation e-mail from Uber to use Uber for Business, or use their Uber for Business  account if they already created one. Is it possible to redirect the users to create or login using their Business account? Now it always gives the possibility to create a new account when opening the app using the Deeplink, but we don't want users to think they need to enter their creditcard details and travel using their personal account.

Many thanks for your replies in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The client_id is only used to track deep link calls and provide attribution to earn through our affiliate program.

2) It is not currently possible to force a user to login via the uber for business invite link via a deeplink. They need to login with their uber account and than accept the invite from the email they receive when enrolled in the uber for business organization.